# Node export to POT for translation

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I think I'm missing something pretty basic here.

I'd like to be able to export all node content as POT files to send along with the other POT files for translation.

I have i18n installed, and a handful of dependencies and "Translation template extractor".

I am able to export nearly everything on the site (menus, taxonomy, strings from modules, etc) but I do not see an option to export "nodes" or "node content".

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't.

I maintain the [Translation Management Tool](https://drupal.org/project/tmgmt) project, that offers a way to export nodes and other translatable content as XLIFF. There is no POT export option but it should be possible write an export format for that.